# Add new databases to existing ASP.net Core 1.0 Webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-core, database-connection

I've been developing a web application for the company I work for, and I'm looking to implement a brand new database to the existing project in VS 2015.

I've been using https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html as a guide, however, I'm having a hard time understanding some of the concepts that are discussed there, as I have been working with it for only a month or so. I had intended to set the database up at the beginning, but a week went by with no progress, so I just started designing the UI, intending to link the database in once we had a working UI.

We would like to have individual user accounts, so right there, the tutorial does not fall within our scope.

The purpose of the web application is invoicing, among other features as it matures. It will have users sign up for a subscription, which gives them access to their own database (Or tables, if that is possible to regulate for multiple users)

I did add another project to the existing project, so now you have this file structure:

src > MainWebapp; src > invoices.AspNetCore.NewDb

I created the project with individual user accounts as the authorization, with intent of using it as the database(for testing).

I installed Entity Framework on the Main Webapplication, do I need to install it on the "Database" as well?

I then went into the MainWebapp startup.cs file, and pasted this code from the tutorial in.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        // Database Connection
        var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=invoices.AspNetCore.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

    }
```

The issue is `services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));`

I do not understand the purpose of this line in terms of the database connection. If someone could explain it to me differently, maybe something will click.

Is there a more comprehensive guide for beginners and databases with ASP.net core 1.0?

Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use appsettings.json file to set your connection there.

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
  "InstrumentationKey": ""
 },
 "ConnectionStrings": {
  "DBConnection":"Server=YourServerName;Database=YourDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=False; User Id=UserName;Password=UserPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
 },
 "Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "System": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Information"
  }
 }
}
```

Then in startup.cs you will just have this:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));
```

This is only to get your connection string to database. BloggingContext is your DataBaseContext where your models are mapped with database tables.

And if you need to setup brand new database (empty) than you can start with code first approach. First build your models and run database migrations and database updates. This will build your database structure and it will build you DBContext automatically. Then with scaffolding you can create your controllers for that models.